# IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration when dockerize project

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, dotnetopenauth

I have 2 projects `IdentityServer` and `bankAccount.api`

identityServer address : `https://localhost:5001`
bankaccount address : `http://localhost:5005`

When the project runs outside of Docker, everything works fine and all endpoints in the bankaccount.api are executed using tokens received from identityserver
Now when we run the projects in Docker, the following error appears

```
IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from:
'https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

Yml file settings:

```
      identityserver:
    container_name: identityserver
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=Server=sqlsrvdb;Database=IdentityDb;User Id=sa;Password=123456"
      - "Data:Seed=true"
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/identityserver.pfx
    depends_on:
      - sqlsrvdb
    ports:
      - "5001:443"
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro

  bankaccount.api:
    container_name: bankaccount.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=Server=sqlsrvdb;Database=AccountDb;User Id=sa;Password=123456"
      - "GrpcSettings:CountryUrl=http://country.grpc"
      - "GrpcSettings:CustomerUrl=http://customer.grpc"
      - "GrpcSettings:CurrencyUrl=http://currency.grpc"
      - "GrpcSettings:WalletUrl=http://wallet.grpc"
      - "CacheSettings:ConnectionString=redisdb:6379"
      - "CacheSettings:InstanceName=bankaccount-redis"
      - "IdentityServer:Uri=https://identityserver"
    depends_on:
      - sqlsrvdb
    ports:
      - "5005:80"
```

If I just run the identityserver in Docker and the other project outside Docker still works properly

Comment: hi did you find any solution.. i ran to the same problem. if there is i really appreciate if you share.